# There are differences between Arduino's Serial Monitor and HyperTerminal?

Tags: serial-port, arduino, monitor, hyperterminal

I'm using Arduino and Windows HypertTerminal because it is more useful to work but I don't understand the reason why the same code does not work equal in HyperTerminal and Serial Monitor.

Serial Monitor:

```
- Autoscroll
- No line ending
- 9600 baud
```

HyperTerminal:

```
- 9600 baud
- Data bits: 8
- No parity
- Stop bit: 1
- No flux control
- ASCII Setup - Receiving: wrap lines that exceed terminal width
```

Comment: What code are you talking about?

Comment: for example [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290981/how-to-transmit-a-string-on-arduino) one in the beggining

Comment: Can you tell us "how" they are not equal. I mean what do they do differently. I have used HyperTerminal before and it worked fine for me.

Comment: @Johnb in the example I said, with Serial Monitor you can write a string and then when you click enter/send it prints the full string, with HyperTerminal everytime you press a key, this char is printed. I tryed several things... Sometimes it looks good on Serial Monitor but nothing happens in HyperTeminal. Sometimes I need to have echo activated, sometimes not.