# Global Variable with two values in different functions Arduino

Tags: c, function, arduino, global-variables, hardware

I'm using a global String variable called IDCartao to save the id from rfid card. After reading the id I search for them on a server with the enc28j60, if the id is on server I make a beep, if not I make two beeps.

But, I'm having problems with the global String IDCartao which in function loop it has the correct value of ID, but when I search for this value in another function called my_callback I don't have the correct value, I just have the empty string "".

```
/**
 * Pinagem Leitor RFID:
 * CLK     - Pino 13
 * MISO    - Pino 12
 * MOSI    - Pino 11
 * SDA     - Pino 10
 * RST     - Pino 09
 * GND     - GND Arduino
 * 3.3     - 3.3v do Arduino
 * NC      - Não Conectado
 */

/**
 * Pinagem Módulo Ethernet:
 * 5v     - Não Conectado
 * LNT    - Não Conectado
 * CLK    - Não Conectado
 * SO     - Pino 12
 * WOL    - Não Conectado
 * SCK    - Pino 13
 * ST     - Pino 11
 * RST    - Não Conectado
 * CS     - Pino 8
 * Q3     - 3.3v do Arduino
 * GND    - GND Arduino
 */

/**
 * Pinagem de Outros componentes:
 * BUZZER  - Pino 7
 */

//DECLARAÇÃO DAS BIBLIOTECAS UTILIZADAS NO PROJETO
#include <SPI.h> //Biblioteca que permite a comunicação com dispositivos SPI (Serial Peripheral Interface), sendo o Arduino como dispositivo principal
#include <MFRC522.h> //Biblioteca do Leitor RFID
#include <EtherCard.h> //Biblioteca do Módulo Ethernet


//DECLARAÇÃO DOS PINOS UTILIZADOS NO ARDUINO
#define PINO_SDA 10 //Constante que define onde o pino SDA do leitor RFID está ligado
#define PINO_RST 9 
#define BUZZER 7

MFRC522 mfrc522 (PINO_SDA, PINO_RST); //Cria instância MFRC522
static byte mymac[] = { 0x74,0x69,0x69,0x2D,0x30,0x31 }; //mac do módulo ethernet
byte Ethernet::buffer[500];
static uint32_t timer;
const char website[] PROGMEM = "192.168.0.103"; //endereço IP do servidor no Raspberry Pi
String conteudo;        //Armazena nessa variável todas as informações contidas no servidor
unsigned int tamanho;   //variável para guardar o tamanho do retorno do servidor
static char *IDCartao;

//ESCOPO DAS FUNÇÕES
void lerID ();
void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len);
void acessoLiberado();
void acessoNegado();
void testaValor();

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println ("Iniciando setup");

  
  SPI.begin();
  pinMode (BUZZER, OUTPUT);
  mfrc522.PCD_Init(); //Inicia MFRC522 (Leitor RFID)
  delay(100);
  if (ether.begin(sizeof Ethernet::buffer, mymac, 8) == 0) {
    Serial.println("Falha ao acessar o Modulo Ethernet");
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Modulo Ethernet conectado!");
  }
  if (!ether.dhcpSetup()) {
    Serial.println("DHCP failed");
  }
  ether.printIp("IP:  ", ether.myip);
  ether.printIp("GW:  ", ether.gwip);  
  ether.printIp("DNS: ", ether.dnsip);

  if (!ether.dnsLookup(website)) {
    Serial.println("DNS failed");
  }
  ether.printIp("SRV: ", ether.hisip);
  delay(100);
  IDCartao = (char*) calloc (12, sizeof(char));
  Serial.println("Setup finalizado!");
  Serial.println ("Aproxima");
  *IDCartao = "WAGNER";
}

void loop() {
  ether.packetLoop(ether.packetReceive());
  //String card = lerID();
  //card.toCharArray(IDCartao, card.length()+1);
  //*IDCartao = lerID();
  lerID();
  if (IDCartao[0] != '\0') { //Se um cartão tiver sido aproximado e sua ID lida com sucesso
    //Serial.print ("ID DO CARTAO: ");
    //Serial.write (IDCartao);
    delay(100);
    if (millis() > timer) {
      Serial.println("VAI LER SITE");
      timer = millis() + 5000;
      Serial.println();
      testaValor();
      ether.browseUrl(PSTR("/"), "", website, my_callback);
    }
    delay(5000);
    testaValor3();
    Serial.println("CONTEUDO:");
    Serial.print(conteudo);
  }
  
}

void testaValor() {
  Serial.println ("DENTRO DO TESTA VALOR");
  Serial.write(IDCartao);
  Serial.println ("\nSUCESSO");
}
void testaValor2() {
  Serial.println ("DENTRO DO TESTA VALOR 2");
  Serial.write(IDCartao);
  Serial.println ("\nSUCESSO");
}
void testaValor3() {
  Serial.println ("DENTRO DO TESTA VALOR 3");
  Serial.write(IDCartao);
  Serial.println ("\nSUCESSO");
}

void lerID () {
     if (mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent ()) {
       if (mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial ()) {
         String conteudorfid = "";
         byte letra;
         for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++) {
           conteudorfid.concat (String (mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
           conteudorfid.concat (String (mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
         }
         conteudorfid.toUpperCase ();
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < conteudorfid.substring(1).length(); i++) {
          IDCartao[i] = conteudorfid.substring(1)[i];
         }
         i++;
         IDCartao[i] = '\0';
       }
       
     //Serial.println(IDCartao); //ID do cartão lida com sucesso
     }
     else {
      IDCartao[0] = '\0';
     }
}

/**
 * Função que faz a leitura do servidor armazenando seu conteudo numa String
 */
void my_callback (byte status, word off, word len) {
  testaValor2();  
  Ethernet::buffer[off+500] = 0;

  conteudo = (const char*) Ethernet::buffer + off;
  
  String verifica(IDCartao);
  
  if (conteudo.indexOf(verifica) > 0) { //procura pela ID do cartão no servidor
    Serial.println("Acesso liberado");
    Serial.println(verifica);
    Serial.print ("POSICAO: ");
    Serial.println (conteudo.indexOf(verifica));
    acessoLiberado();
  }
  else {
    Serial.println ("ACESSO NEGADO!");
    Serial.print ("CARTAO VERIFICA: ");
    Serial.println (verifica);
    Serial.print ("IDCartao: ");
    Serial.write (IDCartao);
    acessoNegado();  
  }
}

void acessoLiberado() {
  tone(BUZZER, 1000); //1kHz
  //digitalWrite (LED_VERDE, HIGH);
  delay (300);
  noTone (BUZZER);
  //digitalWrite (LED_VERDE, LOW);
  *IDCartao = "";
}

void acessoNegado() {
  tone (BUZZER, 1000);
  //digitalWrite (LED_VERMELHO, HIGH);
  delay (150);
  noTone (BUZZER);
  delay (150);
  tone (BUZZER, 1000);
  delay (150);
  noTone (BUZZER);
  //digitalWrite (LED_VERMELHO, LOW);
  *IDCartao = "";
}
```

This is what happens. Look at the function testaValor2(), is the second function which is called but she is called after testaValor3(). I don't know why this is happening. Sorry for the bad quality

[image]

Comment: Not saying that English is the only language in the world, but you might get more help if you translate most words (comments, identifiers), creating more readable code; for most people. Just reduce the barriers. Have mercy ;-)

Comment: I also cannot help thinking that it might not be an MCVE.(http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The function `lerID` doesn't always return a string. Just look at what happens in the `else { }` part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When multiple functions are editing the global variable, you need to make them volatile. For instance, instantiate `IDCartao` like this:

```
volatile String IDCartao;
```

This forces Arduino to get the latest value of `IDCartao` from memory every time it is requested.

More info here: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/volatile

Comment: Thanks for yous answer mineralwasser, but now i'm having another trouble.

I'm now using volatile String but when I compile the code I get some error messages, like this: 

no matching function for call to 'HardwareSerial::println(volatile String&)'

Do you know what i need to do to solve this problem?

Comment: It might be because you're using String object (C++/Wiring) but the function uses C strings. Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290981/how-to-transmit-a-string-on-arduino.
Basically, you need to convert to CharArray (char*):

`char* cString = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*(outMessage.length() + 1);`

`outMessage.stoCharArray(cString, outMessage.length() + 1);`

`Serial1.write(cString);`

Comment: On second thought, don't use volatile String. Use char arrays instead. Source: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=225061.0

Comment: I changed to char array but the same problem is occuring. But after many tests i saw the problem. Is only on my_callback function that the value of IDCartao is null. I don't know why this is happening, do you know or do you have any idea? If i verify the value after calling this function, the value is correct, is only inside the function...

Comment: How did you perform your 'test'? Does it compile now? The fact that you get a `null` instead of and empty string sounds like it is a different problem. Your `lerID()` function doesn't always return a string, due to missing `else` case. Try making it return some kind of string like 'invalid'

Comment: Sorry @mineralwasser, i forgot to update the code here. Now i add a image to show you what is happening in my case. Look at the functions `void testaValor()`, `void testaValor2()` and `void testaValor3()`. `testaValor()` is the first wich is called, `testaValor2()` is called inside the function `my_callback` and `testaValor3()` is called after. But in my tests `testaValor3()` is called before `testaValor2()`, and when `testaValor2()` is called, the value of `IDCartão` is not the same anymore. Sorry for the bad quality of the image. I hope you understand! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I solve the problem, thanks for help. When i call the function `my_callback` the `loop`function continues parallel, so when i was checking for ID the ID was changed in the main function. That's it.